# JavaFX JDK 8: When turning the camera around the coordinate system turns around, but not the mouse coordinates

Tags: coordinates, mesh, javafx-8, perspectivecamera

I am very much stuck with my app and I am not seeing any examples where someone is doing what I am doing.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lqzoegg5v8drzog/nLxDuIVAh0

I have a 3D world and I load TriagleMesh objects into the 3D world from STL files.  The 3D world is created using many examples from Oracle using xforms.  I can turn the camera around the 3D world and all is fine.

When the 3D world has the X+ to the right and I move my objects with the mouse to the right the objects actually go right.  When I turn the world around so that the X+ is to the left the objects move to the left when I move my mouse to the right

The application is currently using getScreenX and getScreenY on the MouseEvent dragged event handler.  I have tried getSceneX and getSceneY and it acts the same way.  When I use getX and getY the objects jump around all over the place and the coordinates that are returned from getX and getY change constantly.  This is most likely because the object is moving and the getX and getY coordinates return where the mouse is in relation to the object before the move.  Lets say I do use getX and getY and I rotate the object then its coordinate system changes.  If it had X+ to the right it will be to the left.  So if I then try to move the object to the right it moves to the left

I am thinking I need to use getScreenX/Y and then somehow translate the mouse coordinates depending on the rotation of the camera.  How would I do that in JavaFX?

**Edit 1**
Sorted

I was given the following code in this jira https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-35178

```
final Rectangle mousePlane = new Rectangle(800, 800, Color.TRANSPARENT);
mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(true);
mousePlane.setDepthTest(DepthTest.DISABLE); // this makes the plane to be picked even if there are objects closer to the camera
// + translation and rotation so it's parallel to your plane

When an object is dragged, it does this:

cube.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        cube.setMouseTransparent(true); // cube will not be picked
        mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(false); // mousePlane will be pickable
        cube.startFullDrag(); // see javadoc, this redirects drag events from the origin (cube) to the picked target (which will be mousePlane)
    }
});

+ some cleanup:

cube.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        cube.setMouseTransparent(false);
        mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(true);
    }
});

and now the movement itself:

        mousePlane.setOnMouseDragOver(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseDragEvent event) {
                Point3D coords = event.getPickResult().getIntersectedPoint();
                double x = coords.getX();
                double y = coords.getY();
                double z = coords.getZ();

                coords = mousePlane.localToParent(new Point3D(x, y, z)); //mouseplane has the same parent as the real plane and objects like cube

                // You might need to adjust this depending on your hierarchy and transformations
                cube.setTranslateX(coords.getX());
                cube.setTranslateY(coords.getY());
                cube.setTranslateZ(coords.getZ());
            }
        });
```

What I did was place the drag detected code in my Gizmo object.  The Gizmo would set the MouseTransparent to true and startFullDrag.  It then called the GizmoViewer so that GizmoViewer could set the mousePlane MouseTransparent.  This allows the drag to be detected by the mousePlane and not the Gizmo.  I also set a flag in GizmoViewer dragJustStarted = true;  When I then start dragging and the OnMouseDragOver fires on the mousePlane it would setup the values for mouseOldX, mousePosX, mouseOldY, mousePosY and if it detects that it is the first time the drag is executed it would exit.  When the drag then executes again I have all the correct mouse values and I can drag with a smile

Setup of the mouse plane

```
private void setupMousePlane() {

    mousePlane.setLayoutX(-800 / 2);
    mousePlane.setLayoutY(-800 / 2);
    mousePlane.setOpacity(0.7);
    mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(true);
    mousePlane.setDepthTest(DepthTest.DISABLE); // this makes the plane to be picked even if there are objects closer to the camera

    mousePlane.setOnMouseDragOver(new EventHandler<MouseDragEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseDragEvent me) {
            if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown() && me.isShiftDown()) {
                //do nothing, we are rotating on the gizmo
            } else if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                Point3D coords = me.getPickResult().getIntersectedPoint();
                mouseOldX = mousePosX;
                mouseOldY = mousePosY;
                mousePosX = coords.getX();
                mousePosY = coords.getY();

                double z = coords.getZ();

                coords = mousePlane.localToParent(new Point3D(mousePosX, mousePosY, z)); //mouseplane has the same parent as the real plane and objects like cube
                mousePosX = coords.getX();
                mousePosY = coords.getY();
                mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
                mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);

                if (dragJustStarted) {
                    dragJustStarted = false;
                } else {

                    double modifier = 10;
                    double modifierFactor = 0.15;
                    double yFlip = 1.0;
                    double flip = -1.0;

                    for (Gizmo gizmo : gizmoSelectionHelper.getSelection()) {
                        gizmo.getGizmoXform2().t.setX(gizmo.getGizmoXform2().t.getX() - flip * mouseDeltaX * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
                        gizmo.getGizmoXform2().t.setY(gizmo.getGizmoXform2().t.getY() + yFlip * mouseDeltaY * modifierFactor * modifier * 0.3);  // -
                        configureGizmoPivot(gizmo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    world.getChildren().addAll(mousePlane);
}
```

Gizmo/Screen object drag detected

```
private final EventHandler mouseDragDetectedHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            Gizmo gizmo = (Gizmo) me.getSource();
            gizmo.setMouseTransparent(true);
            gizmo.startFullDrag();
            gizmo.getGizmoViewer().startDraggingGizmo(me);
        }
    }
};
```

Gizmo mouse released (just beginning of method that is important to this problem)

```
private final EventHandler mouseReleasedHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        Gizmo gizmo = (Gizmo) me.getSource();
        if (MouseButton.PRIMARY == me.getButton()) {
            gizmo.setMouseTransparent(false);
            gizmo.getGizmoViewer().stopDraggingGizmo();
```

GizmoViewer

```
public void startDraggingGizmo(MouseEvent me) {
    // mousePlane will be pickable
    mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(false);

    dragJustStarted = true;
}

public void stopDraggingGizmo() {
    mousePlane.setMouseTransparent(true);
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  My MouseEvent coordinates are jumping around as well.

Comment: Yep mine is working perfectly.  The code posted above will help you.  I also posted a link to all my code above

Comment: Thanks!  I was adding the MouseEvent to the object instead of the node, so the coordinates were all in object space and not node space.